# Auto renewable IN-App Subscriptions returns multiple transactions and "Sign-In required" dialogs

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

I am implementing Auto renewable Subscriptions in my App. Whenever I launch my app, " func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])" is called with multiple transactions. I am not sure why is this happening. May be because of "restore" functionality. I have implemented "RestoreCompletedTransactions" when user hits the Restore Button. I am running into issue either I get multiple dialogs for "Sign-In required"and/or I get so many transactions without calling anything. I am making sure I finish transaction. Please help!!

Comment: On my app launch, " func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])" is called with multiple transactions is not getting called for me but still I am getting multiple dialogs for "Sign-In required"

Comment: Hey, have to got the solution of this?

Comment: It is only in SandBox Environment. In live Environment, no such alerts will be there. Please make sure that you "FINISH" all the transactions, also after restoring the purchases.